# Mudar cor de letra após texto passar por uma div?

Tags: css

Eu tenho uma `div` que tem `position: fixed`, ou seja, acompanha o `scroll`. Mas tenho um problema. Visto que a `div` tem texto com uma cor, se passar por cima de uma `div` que esteja mais escura, o texto não será visível. Existe alguma forma de aplicar na `css` ou `js` para quando ele chegasse a essa `div` mudasse para outra cor?

Este é o código que tenho:

```
<div style="position:fixed;right:10px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-5x"></i></div>
```

Sei que não devo utilizar `style` na linha mas como é só enquanto fase de testes, estou a fazer assim para a mais fácil manipulação do código.

Ouvi falar do método `mix-blend-mode` mas não consegui pô-lo em prática. Como é que conseguiria utilizar esse método?

Comment: Um jeito de fazer isso é calcular o `scrollTop` da do window/body e o `scrollTop` do texto estático. e verifica se está no scroll desejado, caso sim aplica a css.

Comment: Leia isso aqui e veja se ajuda: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Só um z-index para jogar essa div fixa para cima de todo o conteúdo não resolveria seu problema? Ela tem alguma cor de Background, ou só o texto?

Comment: @hugocsl Eu tenho uma `div` mais escura com um fundo escuro. A suposta `div` presa ao `scroll` é aquela indicada no código

Comment: Cara está meio difícil de entender, se vc puder colocar o código completo do HTML e CSS vai ficar mais fácil para te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: @hugocsl https://jsfiddle.net/dagncLy4/ Está vendo como o fundo desaparece por ser branco e mudando para o escuro aparece? É mais ou menos isso que desejo mas sem o background circular, quero que mude o text se passar por cima da div preta

Answer (score -2):

Utilize o :hover conforme exemplo abaixo:

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exemplo alteração de cor do texto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="divMain">Seu texto aqui</div>
    Conteudo do site
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.divMain {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
}

.divMain:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Você pode ver em https://jsfiddle.net/mytq5y68/

Comment: Cara ele não quer o efeito no :hover, ele quer no evento do Scroll do navegador!

Comment: Não era isto que eu queria, não é para ter o efeito de quando ele passa o rato na div, mas sim quando ela toca noutra div